# How to use factorial with subset of X

Tags: factorial

Wording of question is a little strange - let me explain:

take 8 as X

X! = 40320

and that's the possibilities of an 8-character string, like 'abcdefgh'. Does this number include possibilities of say 'abc' and 'dse' or is it strict to using all 8 characters?

Comment: It is just strings with exactly $8$ characters. Do you see why? Do you need to include shorter strings? If so, please edit that into your question and we can help you with that. Or perhaps you can figure it out yourself! Either is fine.

Comment: It only includes 8 character strings! Please note that also 'aaaabbbb' is excluded as you only allow permutations! Is this on purpose?

Comment: @TheCount ah I see thank you :) and sure if you know of a way to figure it out as I can't haha

Comment: @M.Winter that;s the whole 8! / 2! sorta stuff?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs I'm not sure what you mean. I want to say that repeating the same letter twice is prohibited when using this counting.

Answer (score 0):

If we have $8$ distinct things, we can arrange them in a variety of ways. We have $8$ choices for the first thing, then since we have used one, we have only $7$ choices for the second thing, $6$ for the third, etc. So we have $8\times 7\times 6\times 5\times 4\times 3\times 2\times 1$ ways to arrange the $8$ things. This is called "$8$ *factorial*", and denoted $8!$.

If we want to make only arrangements of $3$ things from our set of $8$ different things. There are $8\times 7\times 6$ ways. Do you see why?

If, for example, $3$ of our $8$ objects are identical, then there will be $8!/3!$ ways to arrange the $8$ objects in different ways. Do you see why here as well?